# Prevent a function to be overriden again

Tags: javascript

I have a script loaded from external source after `loadPlayer` is loaded that looks like

```js
function loadElement() {
    new YT.Player('youtube', {})    
}
```

also I am using in my TS file

```js
function loadPlayer() {
    new window.YT.Player('youtube id', { ...somesettings })
}
```

however, the function `loadPlayer` is being executed first, then `loadElement` is creating new YT Player object which I do not want to happen. Are there any ways I can prevent this from happening? I tried adding Object freeze in loadPlayer or playing with proxy but it doesn't seem to work. Also I don't have a possibility to remove the external script. I need to make some workaround.

Comment: *"however, the function loadPlayer is being loaded first..."* Is it being **loaded** (created) first, or loaded and **executed** first?

Comment: Sorry, `loadPlayer` is being executed first, then `loadElement` is being executed and overriding the `YT.Player` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options for you:

1. Override `window.YT.Player` so only you can use it.
2. Prevent the other script from loading at all.

### Override `window.YT.Player` so only you can use it

Assuming it's not a non-configurable binding, you can override the `YT.Player` property from within `loadPlayer`:

```
let OriginalYTPlayer;
function loadPlayer() {
    new window.YT.Player('youtube id', { ...somesettings })
    OriginalYTPlayer = window.YT.Player;
    window.YT.Player = function() { };
}
```

That makes any calls to `YT.Player` do nothing. If you need to use it, you can use `OriginalYTPlayer` instead. Of course, this may mess up other things you're relying on that you haven't mentioned.

### Prevent the other script from loading

Assuming that the other script is a *script*, not a module, and that it's **loaded** after your script is loaded, you can blow it up and prevent it from loading by defining `loadElement` yourself using a `let` or `const`:

```
function loadPlayer() {
    // ...
}
const loadElement = null;
```

Then, when the other script is loaded, it blows up with an error and doesn't execute at all:

```html
<script>
const loadElement = null;
</script>
<script>
function loadElement() {
    new YT.Player('youtube', {})    
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this and still doesnt seem to work, Whenever I try to do it like
`YTPlayer = { ...window.YT }` then when I change window.YT setting, I see it changes in `YTPlayer` as well, I think there is some problem with referencing.

Comment: @kakad - I don't know what you mean by *"...when I change `window.YT` setting..."*.

Comment: `YTPlayer = window.YT` `YTPlayer.Player = { ...new window.YT.Player('id', { events: onStateChange: onPlayerChange})}` the events dont seem to work at all

Comment: @kakad - Why are you replacing the constructor function with an object?

Comment: Same thing happens if I dont use `{...}`, event doesn't fire at all

Comment: @kakad - What are you doing instead? You don't seem to be doing what's in the answer above.